# Can an app get root access on rooted phone if I don't grant it?

Tags: root-access, security

If I root my phone, are there any ways (except for, of course, Android bugs -> exploits) for an app to get root privilege without being allowed (through the SuperUser app popup) to do so?

Followup - if I root my phone but don't allow any apps to use it, is the phone as secure as it was before rooting?

Comment: What root and method did you use (device, ROM, and Android versions would be useful too)? If SuperSU or Magisk and you flashed it with a custom recovery, you are pretty safe... but some ROMs and root methods do not install a proper manager and just grant access on demand. More information is needed.

Comment: If you ignore the bugs and exploits in the superuser mechanism/process of your SU manager app and binary as well, than yeah, allowing no app is same as not having root access, except that apps can detect that your device can grant root access.